# Chrome extension - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: console.log is not a function

Tags: google-chrome-extension, async-await

I am new to Chrome extension and I suspect that my issue relates to a question of context but I can not find the answer...

I am doing an Hello world test snippet to try to write to a file and that part works. However, in the promise returned from my async function I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: console.log is not a function

Here is the code

```
console.log("Testing file write")

async function saveFile() {
  // create a new handle
  const newHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker();

  // create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to
  const writableStream = await newHandle.createWritable();

  // write our file
  await writableStream.write("Hello world!!!");

  // close the file and write the contents to disk.
  await writableStream.close();
}

function onClick() {
  saveFile().then(() => {
    console.log('Saved data in file');
  });
}

document.getElementById("testbutton").addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

For reference, the html is

```
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <button id='testbutton' type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first console.log at the top works perfectly.

Comment: This code can't produce such error, and it works for me as-is, so it's either a bug in the browser (e.g. maybe it can't show the picker inside the popup depending on the OS and you'll need to do it in a separate tab) or the actual code is different.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I removed unrelated code and did not retest. There was an error in that part.